# JSONObject timeout

Tags: android, json

So every time I start my application, I use JSONObject to get some values from my server. The thing is, if the server is down or slow, the application stops. Whats the best way to overcome this problem?

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);
  try {
     int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
     //it stops here
     if (success == 1) { ... }
  } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: Cache the response locally, and only update every so often, using old data if the update fails.

Comment: shouldnt you also have the `makeHttpRequest` inside a try/catch just in-case something happens ie. you get a timeout exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a designing problem rather than programatic problem. If your server is down, there is no code to bring it back ;)

So think about the best approach for yourself of working in offline mode, and implement it.

- Use cached data
- Inform the user that there is no connection
- Consider using `Android.forceServerOnline()`

Answer (score 1):

1 - If possible, you can make it in background and update when done.

2 - If you need the info to start app, you can place a reasonably timeout to the connection and a quick splash screen while you load that data.